# logout user via RESTful call (invalidate session)

Tags: java, ejb, restful-authentication, logout

I'm using JBoss to provide a bunch of RESTful services to a Flex-based RIA. Anyway, I managed through some pain to realize a login (using form-based login) but I'm struggeling with providing a RESTful method to log the user out.
In a JSP I can simply call something like:

```
session.invalidate()
```

How can I do this with JBoss, Resteasy that uses stateless session beans to implement the RESTful services?

Comment: are you keeping data in session?

Comment: I'm not keeping any data in the session. I just need it for authentication.

Comment: What security service are you using?  Are you using Spring Security?  Did you roll your own login service?  In other words, does your application directly access the session or access it indirectly through another service?

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of googeling I created a solution:

This is the local interface of my RESTful service bean:

```
@Local
@Path("/Rest")
public interface SessionController {
...
    @GET
    @Path("/logout/")
    @Produces("text/xml")
    String logout(@Context HttpServletRequest req);
}
```

And this is the implementation:

```
@RolesAllowed({ "TheBoss", "SomeUser", ... })
@SecurityDomain("mysqlLogin")
@Stateless
public class SessionControllerBean implements SessionController {

    ...

    public String logout(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        ...
        req.getSession().invalidate();
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Pretty simple as you can see. As I might have imagined already dependency injection is the trick. With the @Context annotation I can ask JBoss to inject the HTTPServletRequest from which I can get the session and call invalidate.

The bean is being called via resteasy as a RESTful service.

While developing with Java EE I find that I spend more time tracking down how to configure things in all these xml files (maven configuration is pure hell), which API's to use and how and which bean to inject than actually developing functionality.

Comment: This method doesn't work for Single Sign On mode. I have issue with Jboss